# Recebendo o erro "is not a function" para uma função declarada

Tags: javascript

Estava eu escrevendo meu js, quando me deparo com o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: xyz is not a function
```

Lançado a partir do código (ilustrado de maneira simples):

```
(function () {

    function abc() {
        var xyz = xyz();
    }

    function xyz() {
        console.log(123);
    }

    abc();

})();
```

Como vocês podem ver, a função está presente logo em seguida, por que então dessa forma recebo esse erro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você também pode usar o `this` e chamar a função externa mesmo possuindo o mesmo nome.

```
(function () {

    function abc() {
        var xyz = this.xyz();
    }

    function xyz() {
        console.log(123);
    }

    abc();

})();
```

Answer (score 3):

Após algum tempo quebrando a cabeça (acreditem), percebi que estou na verdade sobrescrevendo a função por estar utilizando o mesmo nome para a variável:

```
var xyz = xyz();
```

Mudando o nome da variável nesse trecho, funcionou corretamente.

Pode parecer um erro estupido, mas de certa forma me tomou um tempo, espero que possa ajudar à outros não cometerem o mesmo.